# How to slice and join DataFrame values if a certain condition is met

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df:

```
name         data
jack        1.2.3
xander        1.2
```

If there is a 2nd '.' in the data string, I want to drop it and everything after.

As of now I am doing:

```
df.loc[df['data'].str.count('.') == 2, 'data'] = df['data'].str.split('.')
```

which gives back

```
name           data
jack        [1,2,3]
xander          1.2
```

How can I edit the code above to join the resulting list on '.' for the first two elements only to result in this?

```
name           data
jack            1.2
xander          1.2
```

I am trying to do something like this but run into a whole slew of errors (the join either does not join and leaves the list intact or gives back Nan)

```
df.loc[df['data'].str.count('.') == 2, 'data'] =  '.'.join(df['data'].str.split('.')[:2])
```

If there is a better way to do this please let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way:

```
df['data'] = df['data'].str.split('.').str[:2].apply('.'.join)
```

Or use `extract`:

```
df['data'] = df['data'].str.extract('^([^\.]+\.[^\.]+)')
```

Output:

```
     name data
0    jack  1.2
1  xander  1.2
```